# How to find the slope of a line given one point and the fact that it runs tangent to a circle

Tags: algebra-precalculus, circles, slope

There's a circle with radius = 8 feet

The center of the circle is the origin

A person is situated at (12,0) and their line of sight runs tangent to the circle

The problem is to figure out which portion of the y-axis is obstructed by the circle for the person situated at (12,0)

The hint they give me is: Let $a$ be the x-coordinate of the point where line of sight is tangent to the circle; compute the slope of the line using two points (the tangent point and (12,0). On the other hand, compute the slope of line of sight by noting it is perpendicular to a radial line through the tangency point. Set these two calculations of the slope equal and solve for $a$.

To me that makes the tangency point $(a,y)$ as the hint want's me to substitute $a$ for $x$ and I also don't know $y$. Ok so then compute the slope given this scanty info I guess. I get:

$$\frac{-y}{12 - a}$$

Then the hint wants me to set this equal to it's negative reciprocal as that would be the slope of a line perpendicular to this one, so:

$$\frac{12 - a}{y}$$

And then setting them equal *almost but not even close actually* gives me a quadratic equation:

$$-y^2 = a^2 - 24a + 144$$

So I don't know what to do. Any hints about what I 'm doing wrong would be great, any hints about how to properly interpret the hint/problem is appreciated. Also, I realize there would be two lines of sight that are tangent (one in a upper quadrant and the other in a lower) but just focus on the one in the upper or whatever makes it easier for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

See the sketch. We know $OT = 8, OP = 12$. So can you find $PT$ using Pythagoras?

Now using the slope of line through $AP$, you should notice that

$\displaystyle \frac{OT}{PT} = \frac{AO}{OP}~$

You know $OT, PT$ and $OP$. So can you find $AO$? Now the same length is obstructed below x-axis.

Comment: Wow! I had actually considered using the pythagorean theorem in the exact manner you suggest here but I didn't pursue because I didn't think it was a right triangle. OTP is a right triangle correct?!? And the right angle is at point T?!? I'm going to solve this when I get home, let you know how it works out

Comment: @MatthewS. that's correct. $\triangle OTP$ is right at $T$. The line segment from the center of the circle to the point of tangency is always perpendicular to the tangent line. Yes please let me know how it goes and if you need any help.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I solved it your way. I did get mixed up at first though. It seemed to me that `OT/PT = OP/AO` because if you twist OTP counterclockwise about 90 degrees OT would land on OP and PT would land on AO. Isnt this how OTP would land on AOP if OTP were twisted counter clockwise about 90 degrees? Anyways, when i solved it your way I got `+- 96/sqr(80)` and the answer key said `+- (24×sqr(5))/5` which is equal to the answer I got. So thank you, I solved the problem, but I'm still mixed up on the how you correctly corresponded the sides of OTP to AOP

Comment: You are actually rotating clockwise by $90^\circ$ and some more or counter-clockwise by $180^\circ$ and some more. But if that is confusing let's look at angles. If $\angle APO = \theta$, then $\angle TOP = 90^\circ - \theta$ looking at $\triangle TOP$. Similarly looking at $\triangle OAP, \angle OAP = 90^\circ - \theta$. Now compare similar triangles $\triangle TOP$ and $\triangle OAP$. Which side is opposite $\theta$ and which is opposite $90^\circ - \theta$. Does that help?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm still confused. I know that , unless I'm wrong, OTP is a right triangle formed by shooting a line perpendicular to the hypotenuse of triangle AOP through angle AOP. Looking at triangle OTP and AOP I realize that OP is the hypotenuse of triangle OTP and therefore corresponds to AP (hypotenuse) of triangle AOP. I can also see that angle AOP and angle OTP are both right angles. So I correspond these angles and the hypotenuse. I still cant see how one could correctly correspond the legs of these two triangles only provided the lengths of the sides of triangle OTP.

Comment: I have to learn more about similar triangles for sure. I have a tutorial picked out from mathisfun but I haven't read it yet

Comment: Draw two right triangles with one of the angles as $\theta$. Then the other non-right angle is $90-\theta$. Now if the side opposite $\theta$ in first triangle is $a_1$ and in the second triangle is $a_2$ and side opposite $90-\theta$ in first triangle is $b_1$ and in the second triangle is $b_2$, $\frac{a_1}{b_1} = \frac{a_2}{b_2}$. Now please draw and mark angles like I did in my previous comment, you should be able to see why $\frac{OT}{PT} = \frac{AO}{OP}$.

Answer (score 0):

The slope of the tangent line is, as you note, $m = \frac{-y}{12-a}$.

The slope of the radius can be calculated directly because you have two points - the centre at $(0, 0)$ and the point of contact at $(a, y)$. Notice that the value of 12 doesn't seem to appear at all, so you should check that one carefully.

When you equate those two, you will get something that is quadratic in both $a$ and $y$. This is obviously something you want to get away from as quickly as possible, and that's where I'd suggest thinking about what other information you have about the point $(a, y)$. For example, is there an obvious equation that relates $a$ and $y$, maybe with some quadratic terms that would cancel out the ones you get from the gradients?

Answer (score 0):

The radius is perpendicular to the tangent.  Which means that the slopes of the lines are negative reciprocals of each other.

$-\frac {a}{y} = \frac {y}{a - 12}$

$a^2-12a = -y^2\\
a^2 + y^2 = 12a$

The next part is that the point $(a,y)$ on the circle.  And the radius of the cirlce is 8.

$a^2 + y^2 = 8^2$

Now we can substitute between the two equations.

$64 = 12 a\\
a = \frac {16}{3}\\
y = \sqrt {64 - a^2} = \frac {\sqrt {320}}{3} = \frac {8\sqrt{5}}{3}$

$\frac {y}{a-12} = \frac {\frac {8\sqrt {5}}{3}}{ \frac {16}{3}-12} = \frac {8\sqrt 5}{16-36} = -\frac {2\sqrt 5}{5}$

Comment: How is `-a/y` the negative reciprocal of `y/(a -12)`? Isn't `-(a-12)/y` the negative reciprocal of `y/(a-12)`?

Comment: Slope of the radius is $\frac {y}{a}$ and we set this equal to the negative reciprocal of the line from the point of tangency to the given point.

Comment: So the slope of the radius is `y/a` as in `"change in y /change in x"` where `change in x` is represented by `a` and `change in y` is represented by `y`? Then you set the negative reciprocal of that fraction equal to the slope of the line of tangency? Doesn't that make these slopes parallel? Im trying to distinguish how I interpreted the hint and what you did here. You can tell how I interpreted the hint by how I tried to answer the question, which was by setting the slope of the tangency line equal to its negative reciprocal (which should be the radius slope) which led to the gibberish I got.

Comment: If the slopes were the same that would make them parallel.

Comment: But you said you set the negative reciprocal of the radius equal to the slope of tangency, which you did. If the negative reciprocal of the radius is perpendicular to the radius then wouldn't that make it necessarily parallel to the slope of tangency?